# Passing $(this) to jQuery fadeOut callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, effects

I know I need to use a callback so that `html()` doesn't happen until after `fadeOut()`, but inside the `fadeOut()` callback I don't have access to `$(this)` from `.hover`.

I tried passing the selection using `var point`, but it's not working.

```
if(!$.browser.msie) {
    points = $("div.point");
} else {
    points = $("div.flash");
}
```

> **Problem Area**

```
$(points).hover(
    function () {
        var point = $(this);
        $('#features_key').fadeOut('normal', function (point) {
            $('#features_key').html(point.next('.info').clone()).fadeIn('normal');
        });
    },
    function () {
    }
);
```

> **HTML**

```
<div class="feature" id="feature0">
    <div class="point"></div>
    <div class="info"><p>Roof System</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use point as a parameter to your callback for fadeOut. It will hide the point variable you "captured" earlier:

```
$(points).hover(
    function () {
            var point = $(this);

            $('#features_key').fadeOut('normal', function() {
                    $('#features_key').html(point.next('.info').clone()).fadeIn('normal');
            });
    }, 
    function () {
    }
);
```

Comment: Just what I was afraid of, a stupidly simple solution :) Thank you activa.

Answer (score 0):

by putting point as a parameter in the callback function, you are resetting it's value inside that function.